# Vuejs filterBy() returns incorrect values

Tags: javascript, string, filter, vuejs2

I'm working on a filter for an array of objects.

I have an array containing the objects with a property called tags
and an array of tags that i will use later.

My data() looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    tags: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    works: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'one',
        img: '',
        tags: ['red', 'green']
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'two',
        img: '',
        tags: ['red', 'blue']
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'three',
        img: '',
        tags: ['green', 'blue']
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'four',
        img: '',
        tags: ['green']
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'five',
        img: '',
        tags: ['red']
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'six',
        img: '',
        tags: ['blue']
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

on the template y iterate some buttons with the tags like this:

```
<button v-for="(tag, tagInd) in tags" :key="tagInd" @click="filterBy(tag)">{{tag}}</button>
```

and as you can see, there's a method on the buttons that pass the tag as an argument.

the purpose of the method is to return all the objects that has the tag passed in the filterBy(tag) method on the tags property.

the method looks like this:

```
methods: {
  filterBy(tag) {
    let filtered = ''; 
    filtered = this.works.filter(
      elem => { 
        return elem.tags.indexOf(tag) 
      }
    );
    console.log(filtered);
  }
},
```

but something strange happens and that method returns all the objects that DOESN'T have the tag passed as an argument on the tags property. 
what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the callback you are passing to the `filter` method is simply returning the value of `elem.tags.indexOf(tag)`. The `indexOf` method will return `-1` if the parameter value isn't found in the array it's being called on.

That means if the `tag` is not in the array of `tags`, the callback function will return `-1`. And that `tag` value **will not** get filtered out, since `-1` is type-coerced to a Boolean value of `true` (see `!!(-1) === true`).

Additionally, if the `tag` is the first element of the array, the `indexOf` method will return `0`. So that `tag` value **will** get filtered out, since `0` is type-coerced to a Boolean value of `false` (see `!!(0) === false`).

---

All that to say: you just need to explicitly check that the value returned by the `indexOf` call is not equal to `-1`:

```
filtered = this.works.filter(elem => {
  return elem.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
});
```